# How is bias avoided in the selection of members of Constitutional benches in India?

Tags: india

In India, cases *involving a substantial question of law as to the interpretation* of the Constitution of India are resolved by specially appointed [Constitution Benches](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nick_Robinson/publication/228226488_Interpreting_the_Constitution_Indian_Supreme_Court_Constitution_Benches_Since_Independence/links/00b7d526530af7d7f2000000.pdf). This comprises of 5 or more judges of the Supreme Court.

What is the process of appointing these benches? How is impartiality ensured? Are there any published critiques of this selection system, or recommendations to improve this process?